# Remove filter on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to updating some cells after applying a filter to my dataframe.

To be more precise:

- after filtering the column `[‘Item – ENTRY TYPE’]` for values `“FACTU”` and `“Avoir”`...
- I want to check if the total amount in `[“PNS BRUT PSSO”]` is <0, for each customer
- If it is, I want to change the values in `['Item - Entry - Type]` to `"FACTU"`.

Here is an example :

[image]

**For the customer "3177800005", the total in PNS BRUT PSSO is -32,39.**
Then I would like this result :

[image]

When I launch my code, it applies "FACTU" in all the cells.

```
#Filter on AVOIR and FACTU only  
table_final_df1[table_final_df1['Item - Entry Type'].isin(['FACTU', 'AVOIR'])]
# Cast 'Code client' to string and remove '.0'
table_final_df1["Code client"] = table_final_df1["Code client"].astype('str').apply(lambda x : x.replace('.0',''))

# Create new df with 2 columns 'Code client' and 'PNS BRUT PPSO'
new_df = table_final_df1.copy()[["Code client","PNS BRUT PPSO"]]

#Remove duplicate from 'Code Client' and find the sum for each client
new_df.groupby(["Code client"], as_index=False).sum()

# I drop client where sum is >= 0 
new_df.drop(index = new_df[(new_df["PNS BRUT PPSO"] >= 0)].index)

# I keep client where the sum is <0 and cast to a list
marks_list = [str(x) for x in new_df["Code client"].tolist()]

# Use apply for this function : if 'code client' is in 'mark_list' then overwrite 'FACTU' on the column['Item - Entry Type'], either nothing
table_final_df1["Item - Entry Type"] = table_final_df1.apply(lambda x : "FACTU" if x["Code client"] in marks_list else x["Item - Entry Type"], axis = 1)

#Save in local
table_final_df1("data.csv", sep = ';', index = False)
```

Before :

[image]

After :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RJNh.png)

Do you know how to proceed ?

Comment: If you want to update the original dataframe, then operate on the original dataframe, don't operate on a copy! or worse still, a modified version of a filter of a copy of a filter. Don't declare `items_filter `, `new_df`, `newtest`, `marks_list` etc. Operate directly on `table_final_df1`. Redo your code, show us some sample data, and explain specifically where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks @smci, I did some change to my code and edit my post to show some example. I try to change all the variables by directly my table_final_df1 but I've got some issues. For example here `table_final_df1["Item - Entry Type"] = table_final_df1.apply(lambda x : "FACTU" if x["Code client"] in marks_list else x["Item - Entry Type"], axis = 1)` . I'm not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the property loc. I post it here, it can help.

```
    #Filter on AVOIR and FACTU only  
    items_filter = table_final_df1.loc[table_final_df1["Item - Entry Type"].isin(['FACTU', 'AVOIR'])]

    #Cast 'Code client' to string and remove '.0'
    table_final_df1["Code client"] = table_final_df1["Code client"].astype('str').apply(lambda x : x.replace('.0',''))

    # Create new df with 2 columns 'Code client' and 'PNS BRUT PPSO'
    new_df = items_filter.copy()[["Code client","PNS BRUT PPSO"]]
    
    #Remove duplicate from 'Code Client' and find the sum for each client
    newtest = new_df.groupby(["Code client"], as_index=False).sum()

    #I drop client where sum is >= 0 
    newtest.drop(index = newtest[(newtest["PNS BRUT PPSO"] >= 0)].index, inplace = True)

    #I keep client where the sum is <0 and cast to a list
    marks_list = [str(x).replace('.0','') for x in newtest["Code client"].tolist()]

    #Use apply for this function : if 'code client' is in 'mark_list' then overwrite 'FACTU' on the column['Item - Entry Type'], either nothing
    table_final_df1["Item - Entry Type"] = table_final_df1.apply(lambda x : "FACTU" if x["Code client"] in marks_list and x["Item - Entry Type"] in ['FACTU', 'AVOIR'] else x["Item - Entry Type"], axis = 1)

    #Save in local
    table_final_df1("data.csv", sep = ';', index = False)
```